# Add hyperlink within reality composer that can be used on WEB AR

Tags: augmented-reality, realitykit, reality-composer

So Im wondering is there anyway you can add a hyperlink action in reality composer that can be used in web ar?

I can't seem to find an action for this?

The way I'm using the reality file on my website is like so

```
<a href="<...link to .reality file>" rel="ar">
   <img />
</a>
```

any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Hi, does this help you? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/adding_an_apple_pay_button_or_a_custom_action_in_ar_quick_look 
Look at sections: "Display a Custom Banner" and "Detect a Tap" for detection of the tab. It isn't configured in Reality Composer but rather in the link it self:

In short, the link is: 
```
<a rel="ar" id="CustomAction" href="kids‑slide.usdz#callToAction=Browse%20API&checkoutTitle=Kids%20Slide&checkoutSubtitle=Playground%20in%20your%20backyard&price=$145">
    <img src="kids-slide-thumbnail.png">
</a>
```

Comment: Hey @Thor_Bux not really the solution i was hoping for, however this does solve my problem! Thanks :)

Comment: @SmokeyDawson Did you find a solution to imbed the .reality file online?

Comment: @SmokeyDawson Did you identify a way to add a URL within Reality Composer? I'd like to be able to launch a webpage if someone taps a specific object.

Comment: @KDP unfortunately no, the only way I was able to do it was via the approved answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the link is:

`<a rel="ar" id="CustomAction" href="kids‑slide.usdz#callToAction=Browse%20API&checkoutTitle=Kids%20Slide&checkoutSubtitle=Playground%20in%20your%20backyard&price=$145"> <img src="kids-slide-thumbnail.png"> </a>`

Look at sections: "Display a Custom Banner" and "Detect a Tap" for detection of the tab. It isn't configured in Reality Composer but rather in the link it self: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/adding_an_apple_pay_button_or_a_custom_action_in_ar_quick_look